# Configure Service Model for WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a very basic webservice using WCF (C#, .NET 4.0), to return an hello message.

The deployment under IIS 7 and running it is ok, but when I do `svcutil.exe http://localhost:4569/Service.svc?wsdl` through the CMD to test the webservice I get:

> the remote server returned an error: 415 cannot proccess the message
>   because the content type 'aplication/soap+xml charset=utf8'  was not
>   the expected type 'text/xml charset=utf8'

When trying to add the service reference (to create a client) I get

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:4569/Service.svc'. Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://localhost:4569/Service.svc.  The client and service bindings
>   may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot
>   process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..

I'm pretty sure that the problem is under my Web.config file:

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
<services>
         <service name="Service">
             <endpoint name="soap" 
                 address="http://localhost:4569/Service.svc" 
                 binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                 contract="IService" />
             <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                       contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         </service>
         <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
               <behavior>
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
               </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
</services>
         </behaviors>
         <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Anyway, here's my code:

**IService.cs:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string getMessage();
}
```

My service.cs has the method

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string getMessage()
    {
        return "Ola servico";
    }
}
```

I really don't know what is happening, did some tests after some research but no success.

**Service.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>
```

Comment: You're not showing us the **interesting** (and **important**) parts of your config! The `<services>` section in `<system.serviceModel>` on the server side and the contents of the *.svc file! Please add those - otherwise we're left guessing at best....

Comment: is that the entire config file? are the services, bindings and endpoints defined in code?

Comment: The error message would indicate that you're mixing SOAP and REST. It seems you want to retrieve a WSDL, yet it would appear as if you're using the REST binding (`webHttpBinding`) ....

Comment: @marc_s I tried, edited question, but not working..

Comment: @Martin can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: when you say 'running it is ok' do you mean in the browser and have you tried connecting to it via wcftestclient? also, and this may be a stupid question, but is your getMessage() implementing the service contract?

Comment: @Tiago: can you show us the **contents** of your *.svc file???

Comment: @Martin I mean in the browser yes. I make a client through Console Application but when I try to add the Service Reference I get exactly the same error. In my getMessage method as fair as I know I to not implement the service contract... edited my question.

Comment: @marc_s my Service.svc is this: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>

Comment: are you sure ASP.NET4 websites are working on this box? what WINDOWS/IIS version you are using ?

Comment: @vittore I'm sure. I'm running IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Ultimate. My default pool is also set to ASP.NET 4, specifically. I know how to handle IIS / VS, I obviously just don't know how to make this WS going...

Comment: the namespace shouldn't matter with only one service and endpoint, the multiple site bindings could be your problem. since you only have one i'd probably take that out to get it working. otherwise you could try adding a base address and setting your endpoint to have listenUri="http://localhost:4569/" and address=""

Comment: @Martin the curious thing is when I set multiple bindings flag to false, I get the same error again. I'm really not interested on multiple bindings, if you could suggest an approach to a single binding I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no service and endpoint defined in your config. Try adding

```
<services>
  <service name="Service"> <!-- name should match the name in your .svc file (if you open it with a text editor) -->
    <endpoint name="soap" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" />
    <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I tried DonAndre, but it's not working. Edited my question with services section anyway,

Comment: The configuration doesn't work the way you posted it. Services need to be closed before behaviors. The address of your soap endpoint should be an empty string, because this refers to what comes after the .svc in the URL.

Comment: @I know, the code does not even compile that way, it was a mistake putting there, but in my code is correct.

Comment: @Tiago I saw you also have enabled "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests", try disabling it and see again. Maybe the error comes from one of the modules. Also please update the web.config in your question with the version that IIS uses. Apart from the address of your soap endpoint being absolute instead of relative, I can't see a problem with the config.